# Cypher load CSV eager and long action duration

Tags: neo4j, cypher

im loading a file with 85K lines - 19M,
server has 2 cores, 14GB RAM, running centos 7.1 and oracle JDK 8
and it can take **5-10 minutes** with the following server config:

```
dbms.pagecache.memory=8g                  
cypher_parser_version=2.0  
wrapper.java.initmemory=4096  
wrapper.java.maxmemory=4096
```

disk mounted in /etc/fstab:

```
UUID=fc21456b-afab-4ff0-9ead-fdb31c14151a /mnt/neodata            
ext4    defaults,noatime,barrier=0      1  2
```

added this to /etc/security/limits.conf:

```
*                soft      memlock         unlimited
*                hard      memlock         unlimited
*                soft      nofile          40000
*                hard      nofile          40000
```

added this to /etc/pam.d/su

```
session         required        pam_limits.so
```

added this to /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 50
vm.dirty_ratio = 80
```

disabled journal by running:

```
 sudo e2fsck /dev/sdc1
 sudo tune2fs /dev/sdc1
 sudo tune2fs -o journal_data_writeback /dev/sdc1
 sudo tune2fs -O ^has_journal /dev/sdc1
 sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sdc1
 sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sdc1
```

besides that,
when running a profiler, i get lots of "Eagers", and i really cant understand why:

```
 PROFILE LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///home/csv10.csv' AS line
 FIELDTERMINATOR '|'
 WITH line limit 0
 MERGE (session :Session { wz_session:line.wz_session })
 MERGE (page :Page { page_key:line.domain+line.page }) 
   ON CREATE SET page.name=line.page, page.domain=line.domain, 
 page.protocol=line.protocol,page.file=line.file


Compiler CYPHER 2.3

Planner RULE

Runtime INTERPRETED

+---------------+------+---------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Operator      | Rows | DB Hits | Identifiers         | Other                                                  |
+---------------+------+---------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| +EmptyResult  |    0 |       0 |                     |                                                        |
| |             +------+---------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| +UpdateGraph  |    9 |       9 | line, page, session | MergeNode; Add(line.domain,line.page); :Page(page_key) |
| |             +------+---------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| +Eager        |    9 |       0 | line, session       |                                                        |
| |             +------+---------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| +UpdateGraph  |    9 |       9 | line, session       | MergeNode; line.wz_session; :Session(wz_session)       |
| |             +------+---------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| +ColumnFilter |    9 |       0 | line                | keep columns line                                      |
| |             +------+---------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| +Filter       |    9 |       0 | anon[181], line     | anon[181]                                              |
| |             +------+---------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| +Extract      |    9 |       0 | anon[181], line     | anon[181]                                              |
| |             +------+---------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| +LoadCSV      |    9 |       0 | line                |                                                        |
+---------------+------+---------+---------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

all the labels and properties have indices / constrains 
thanks for the help
Lior

Answer (score 3):

He Lior,

we tried to explain the Eager Loading here:

And Marks original blog post is here: http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/10/23/neo4j-cypher-avoiding-the-eager/

Rik tried to explain it in easier terms:

http://blog.bruggen.com/2015/07/loading-belgian-corporate-registry-into_20.html

#### Trying to understand the "Eager Operation"

I had read about this before, but did not really understand it until Andres explained it to me again: in all normal operations, Cypher loads data lazily. See for example this page in the manual - it basically just loads as little as possible into memory when doing an operation. This laziness is usually a really good thing. But it can get you into a lot of trouble as well - as Michael explained it to me:

> "Cypher tries to honor the contract that the different operations
>   within a statement are not affecting each other. Otherwise you might
>   up with non-deterministic behavior or endless loops. Imagine a
>   statement like this:
>   `MATCH (n:Foo) WHERE n.value > 100 CREATE (m:Foo {m.value = n.value + 100});`
>
> If the two statements would not be
>   isolated, then each node the CREATE generates would cause the MATCH to
>   match again etc. an endless loop. That's why in such cases, Cypher
>   eagerly runs all MATCH statements to exhaustion so that all the
>   intermediate results are accumulated and kept (in memory).
>
> Usually
>   with most operations that's not an issue as we mostly match only a few
>   hundred thousand elements max.
>
> With data imports using LOAD CSV,
>   however,  this operation will pull in ALL the rows of the CSV (which
>   might be millions), execute all operations eagerly (which might be
>   millions of creates/merges/matches) and also keeps the intermediate
>   results in memory to feed the next operations in line.
>
> This also
>   disables PERIODIC COMMIT effectively because when we get to the end of
>   the statement execution all create operations will already have
>   happened and the gigantic tx-state has accumulated."

So that's what's going on my load csv queries. MATCH/MERGE/CREATE caused an eager pipe to be added to the execution plan, and it effectively disables the batching of my operations "using periodic commit".  Apparently quite a few users run into this issue even with seemingly simple LOAD CSV statements. Very often you can avoid it, but sometimes you can't."

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. After reading those it is still hard to understand the reason for the "eager" in my case. (Cypher is attached) and also is  5 min loading for 19M normal? Thanks!