# PROFILE and EXPLAIN not showing anything on cypher-shell

Tags: neo4j, cypher

After seeing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31788513/cypher-load-csv-eager-and-long-action-duration), I've been reading [this blog post](https://markhneedham.com/blog/2014/10/23/neo4j-cypher-avoiding-the-eager/) about the need to avoid the need to avoid `Eager` when loading a very large CSV into Neo4J.

In my case, I have a ~27 million line CSV, totaling ~8.5 GB in size. It seems pretty important that I break up my query into several queries to avoid `Eager` transactions.

[EXPLAIN and PROFILE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) both offer ways to "test" a query. In Mark Needham's blog post linked above, he mentions:

> You'll notice that when we profile each query we're stripping off the
>   periodic commit section and adding a 'WITH row LIMIT 0'. This allows
>   us to generate enough of the query plan to identify the 'Eager'
>   operator without actually importing any data.

However, when I try to test my query on the cypher shell with `PROFILE` prepended... nothing happens. I don't get any output or report back.

```
$ ./bin/cypher-shell
Connected to Neo4j 3.3.5 at bolt://localhost:7687 as user neo4j.
Type :help for a list of available commands or :exit to exit the shell.
Note that Cypher queries must end with a semicolon.
neo4j> :begin
neo4j# PROFILE LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///myfile.tsv" AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '\t'
       WITH line LIMIT 0
       MERGE ...
```

I also `EXPLAIN` and saw the same behavior -- no report or output.

If I paste the same `PROFILE ...` command into the Neo4J web interface, I do see the graphical plan show up, and even a warning tab telling me about `EAGER`. That is better than nothing, I suppose, but it's hard to read through this graphical display. I'd really like to use the `cypher-shell` for this, but it bizarrely is not showing anything.

I have also tried piping the `EXPLAIN` or `PROFILE` query to `cypher-shell`, but that just gives me some meta-data, not the actual plan.

```
$ cat query.cypher | ./bin/cypher-shell --format plain
Plan: "EXPLAIN"
Statement: "READ_WRITE"
Version: "CYPHER 3.3"
Planner: "COST"
Runtime: "INTERPRETED"
Time: 155
```

PROFILE:

```
$ cat query.cypher | ./bin/cypher-shell --format plain
Plan: "PROFILE"
Statement: "READ_WRITE"
Version: "CYPHER 3.3"
Planner: "COST"
Runtime: "INTERPRETED"
Time: 285
DbHits: 0
Rows: 1
count(*)
0
```

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: That `:begin` opens a transaction, the query itself won't execute until you end with `:commit`. In this case, you can leave off `:begin` completely, just end the query with a semicolon. Also, since you're only after the query plan here, use EXPLAIN so it doesn't actually execute the query.

Comment: @InverseFalcon would you please make your comment an answer? I can then accept. (and thank you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That :begin opens a transaction, the query itself won't execute until you end with :commit.

In this case, you can leave off :begin completely, just end the query with a semicolon. Also, since you're only after the query plan here, use EXPLAIN so it doesn't actually execute the query.